# Unable to retrieve list of products from Azure API Management through REST API

Tags: rest, powershell, azure, azure-api-management

I'm having trouble retrieving the list of APIM Products from the REST API based on the "apiId" passed in.  I tried using the IDENTIFIER value from the screenshot below:
[image]

However, I get the following error:

***Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"Api not found.","details":null}}
At D:\powershell scripts\testing\test_add_api2.ps1:77 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Header @{ "Authorization ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-Rest 
   Method], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMet 
   hodCommand***

I'm using the following path to retrieve the list of products:

*https://{base url}/apis/{apiId}?api-version=2016-10-10*

I've also verified that the access token is valid for 5 days out.

First, am I using the correct id for "apiId"?  Second, has the path changed recently if I'm using the correct apiId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After speaking with Microsoft support, I figured out the issue.  It turns out there's two different documentations with "Product" in the title under the "Reference" section:  (1) Api Products and (2) Products

I made the mistake of following the documentation under #1.  #2 is the documentation you want to follow in order to get the list of products.  According to that documentation, the path looks like this:

```
GET /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/products?api-version=2016-10-10[&$filter&$top&$skip&expandGroups]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/products

I confirmed that this works.  So in short, use documentation #2 for products, not #1.  Not sure what #1 is used for, but #2 works.

Comment: #1 is used to get lost of products API belongs to.